# How to enable/disable checkbox with radio button?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I am developing one web application where i need to disable/enable check box based on selecting radio button as show below.

```
<sctipt>

    function metaboliteenable() {
        document.getElementById("XT").disabled=false;
    }
    function metabolitedisable() {
        document.getElementById("XT").disabled=true;
    }
</script>


<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Data<br>
    <select id="XT">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

But i above code how can i link radio button with check box?

Comment: when you want to enable selectbox and when you want to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there are minimum two radio buttons otherwise you can use checkbox.Anyways...

you can check the status of your radio button with `.is(':checked')`.

And you can disable your select with `.prop('disabled', 'disabled')`.

And you can monitor the status of your radio button like this:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function () {});
```

Anyways, you can run your code inside that function to disable your select when your radio is not checked.

To demonstrate I've added another radio button so you can disable the first one.
This code basically check for your gender if you are male it will disable the select.

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
    var stat = $('input[value="Male"]').is(':checked');
    if(stat){
        $('select').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else{
        $('select').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female<br>
    <select id="XT">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```